# auto create record of another model while creating a record in one form - Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have two model in my orm i.e. _service & _apple. What I want is I want to create record of _apple with some fields written automatically. As an example, from sale order we can create invoice and when invoice is created, some of the fields of invoice are automatically generated written in record as same as in sale order.

What I have done is:

My service Model

```
class _service(models.Model):
_name = 'se.service'
_rec_name = "service_name"

name = fields.Char(
    'Reference', copy=False, readonly=True, default=lambda x: _('New'))
service_name = fields.Char("Service Name", required=True)
service_department = fields.Many2one('hr.department', "Department Name", required=True, help="Department Name of employee")
service_description = fields.Text("Description", required=True)
service_remarks = fields.Text("Remarks")
service_methodology = fields.Html(string="Methodology")
service_id = fields.One2many('se.objective', 'service_id', string="Objectives", required=True)

@api.model
def create(self, valuees):
    if valuees.get('name', _('New')) == _('New'):
        valuees['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('se.service') or _('New')
    return super(_service, self).create(valuees)

def _create_apple(self):
    inv_obj = self.env['se.apple']
    self.ensure_one()
    se = _service
    invoice = inv_obj.create({
        'apple_name': se.service_name,
        'apple_description': se.service_description,
        'apple_remarks': se.service_remarks
    })
    return invoice


def create_apple(self):
    self._create_apple()
```

My _apple Model

```
class _apple(models.Model):
    _name = 'se.apple'

    apple_name = fields.Char("Apple Name")
    apple_description = fields.Text("Remarks Apple")
    apple_remarks = fields.Text("Remarks Apple")
```

My se.service form:

```
<header>
    <button name="create_apple" string="Create Apple" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
</header>
```

If I do as below:
1. I create a form in se.service.
2. I save the form.
3. I click create_apple button.

I expect:
1. A record automatically created in se.apple
2. Record will have apple_name, apple_description & apple_remarks automatically generated as I have filled in se.service.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: The code I have written is not working. I want to know that what I am missing or I want the way to write method that actually works in my way.

Comment: Any error you have?

Comment: I have created four class. First is se.service which has one2many relation with se.objective and second is se.apple which has one2many relation with se.t. I can create record of se.objective from se.service by clicking create button in se.service model. However, I can't transfer the recordset of se.objective in se.service to se.t in se.apple. I know it can be done because I have seen same thing has been done while creating invoice from sale order. Product added in sale.order are transfered in account.invoice.

sale.order.line >> sale.order ----->>> account.invoice >> account.invoice.line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the current service record in the self so, you can use it directly.
try this updated method.

```
   def _create_apple(self):
        inv_obj = self.env['se.apple']
        self.ensure_one()
        invoice = inv_obj.create({
            'apple_name': self.service_name,
            'apple_description': self.service_description,
            'apple_remarks': self.service_remarks
        })
        return invoice
```